# ImpressPages 4 reflections not creating in server but work in localhost

Tags: php, apache, file-io, centos, impresspages

I have an ImpressPages installation that works fine locally, I pulled the code using git in my centos/apache server and changed the config.php data to have the right database, user and password.

Everything seemed to work fine until I tried to upload an image, the image uploads just fine but the thumbnail is not generated, the image shows in the popup if I set the options to lightbox and publish the page, but the thumbnail does not show, the same happens with the gallery.

This is what I get after uploading an image http://screencast.com/t/FNbeErjrw

I enabled developer mode and debug mode in config.php but there is not any error in the log or the browser console, I set the permissions of the file folder to 777 but even like that the reflection is not created.

Something I noticed is that the folders are created but empty 2015/08/19.

What could be causing it to work in local but not in the server?
How could I debug this if there is not any error?

Comment: Do nice URLs work on your server (mod_rewrite)?

Comment: yes urls rewrite is working, I found out it was a missing php library

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the installer directly in the server instead of cloning it with git and copying the database over, this way I found during the requirement check that **php-gd library** was not installed.

As the logs did not show any error it was kind of difficult to see, but after installing php-gd the thumbnails work fine.

Comment: Happy to hear it. Good luck with ImpressPages!